# How can I get the value of a custom attribute in a dropdownlist using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have dropdownlist on a webform. I need a 'hidden' variable per item in the dropdown list which I can retrieve clientside using the onchange event. 
So on the page load I'm setting a custom attribute after I databind the dropdownlist:

```
For i = 0 To cboNameAL.Items.Count - 1
            cboNameAL.Items(i).Attributes.Add("Charge_Rate", usernamesAdapterDataTable.Item(i).ChargeRate)
Next
```

This works and when I look at my rendered page I see this markup for each item in the dropdownlist

```
<option value="05ab8c45-f7ce-4250-8458-1421e79e8a51" charge_rate="32">dave</option>
```

My javascript function is firing fine from the onchange event, however I can't retrieve the attribute value for Charge_Rate.

I've tried every combination of:

```
var lCharge_Rate = document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>").selectedItem.attributes('Charge_Rate');

var lCharge_Rate = document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>").attributes('Charge_Rate');

var lCharge_Rate = document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>")attr('Charge_Rate');

var lCharge_Rate = document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>").getAttributes('Charge_Rate');
```

Each with either ('Charge_Rate') or ("Charge_Rate") or .Charge_Rate

I've debugged and the best I can do is for my variable lCharge_Rate to be null.
Any ideas?  Happy to rework if it can't be done this way...

Comment: The reason that those do not work, is because you are searching by ID yet there is no ID assigned to the `<option></option>`. If you were to assign the value `05ab8c45-f7ce-4250-8458-1421e79e8a51` as an id, then you can retrieve the charge_rate with `document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>").getAttribute('Charge_Rate');`

Comment: The id refers to the dropdownlist control of which the quoted <option> represents one of the items in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the value of your custom attribute

```
    //This line will load the DOM of dropdown 
    var cboNameAL = document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>");
    //This will return the selected option
    var selectedOption = cboNameAL.options[cboNameAL.selectedIndex];
    //This will give you the value of the attribut
    var charge_rate = selectedOption.attributes.charge_rate.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the options first before you can get the attribute.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("client_id"),
lCharge_Rate = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('charge_rate');

document.write("Charge Rate = "+lCharge_Rate);
```

```html
<select id="client_id">
    <option value="05ab8c45-f7ce-4250-8458-1421e79e8a51" charge_rate="32">dave</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This line of javascript doesn't actually execute though.   Can you explain why I need to select 'the options' first?

Comment: Thanks thebasah - you were on the right track with needing to select options first.  See Rakesh Nalumachu's reply.

Comment: I assume you put ID on the dropdown list, bcause you only mention option on your code without ID. when you select element **document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>")** the result is the dropdown element, but the attribute you want is in the option, that's why you need to select the options property first

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that equals the value of your custom attribute, then use it as you desire. See my example and adjust as needed.

```js
var $divAtribut = $("div").attr("Charge_Rate");
alert($divAtribut);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div Charge_Rate="4424">Click on run to get the attribute</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
<!– my html –>
<select name="custom-select-two">
<option value="1" data-monthvalue="31">Jan</option>
<option value="2" data-monthvalue="28">Feb</option>
<option value="3" data-monthvalue="31">Mar</option>
<option value="4" data-monthvalue="30">Apr</option>
<option value="5" data-monthvalue="31">May</option>
<select>

<!– Get value of option’s custom attribute value from dropdown or select box –>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var monthvalue = $('.custom-select-two :selected').data('monthvalue');
alert(monthvalue); // here comes your dropdown option's custom attribute value
});
</script>

</code>
```

Comment: Hope its usefull anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When answering you should give some [context about what you what your code does](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks.  I think I get what you're suggesting: use dataattributes instead of attributes.  Tried it - amended my code behind to call the attribute 'data-Charge_Rate' and used document.getElementById("<%=cboNameAL.ClientID%>").data('Charge_Rate'); to reference it but unfortunately I got an error when the javascript ran telling me TypeError: document.getElementById(...).data is not a function